# TypeScript: Partially "Partial" type

Tags: typescript

## Environment

TypeScript's version is 3.2.1 and "tsconfig.json" is like below.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  }
}
```

## Question

I'm looking for Partially ["Partial"](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.2.1/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1414) type in TypeScript.

```
type Entity = {
  a: string,
  b: string,
  c?: string,
};

type Ham = MyType<Entity, 'b'>;
/**
 * expected to equal
 * {
 *   a: string,
 *   b?: string, // changed to be optional
 *   c?: string,
 * };
 */
```

---

P.S. Titian and t7yang

Thank you for your replies. 
I checked your types then both types pass compiler's check!

```
const abc = { a: 'a', b: 'b', c: 'c' };
const ab = { a: 'a', b: 'b' };
const ac = { a: 'a', c: 'c' };
const a = { a: 'a' };

// by t7yang
let test1Abc: OptionalKey<Entity, 'b'> = abc;
let test1Ab: OptionalKey<Entity, 'b'> = ab;
let test1Ac: OptionalKey<Entity, 'b'> = ac;
let test1A: OptionalKey<Entity, 'b'> = a;

// by Titian Cernicova-Dragomir    
let test2Abc: PickPartial<Entity, 'b'> = abc;
let test2Ab: PickPartial<Entity, 'b'> = ab;
let test2Ac: PickPartial<Entity, 'b'> = ac;
let test2A: PickPartial<Entity, 'b'> = a;
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `Pick` in conjunction with `Partial` to pick only the properties you want to make optional, while preserving the rest using `Exclude` to get the keys excluding the ones passed in to make optional :

```
type Entity = {
   a: string,
   b: string,
   c?: string,
};

type PickPartial<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>> & Partial<Pick<T, K>> 
type Ham = PickPartial<Entity, 'b'>; // a, b? , c?
```

Comment: It seems to me `type PickPartial<T, K extends keyof T> = Omit<T, K> & Partial<Pick<T, K>>;` works exactly the same and is nicer to read. Or am I missing something here?

I also found the opposite case to be quite useful, where you want to make all fields optional except for a few select ones:
`type PartialExcept<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, K> & Partial<Omit<T, K>>;`

Comment: @iFreilicht `Omit` was a later addition. At the time I wrote this it probably did not exist.

Answer (score 3):

Real simple solution:

```js
type PickPartial<T, K extends keyof T> = Omit<T, K> & Partial<Pick<T, K>>;
type PartialExcept<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, K> & Partial<Omit<T, K>>;
```

Titian's solution was written before [Typescript 3.5, which added the Omit helper](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-5.html#the-omit-helper-type).

Also remember that you can use string unions to pick multiple attributes to be made optional:

```js
type Full = {
  a: string;
  b: string;
  c: string;
}

// These are equivalent
type ARequired = PickPartial<Full, 'b' | 'c'>;
type ARequired = PartialExcept<Full, 'a'>;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
type Entity = {
  a: string,
  b: string,
  c?: string,
};

type OptionalKey<T, O extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, O>> & Partial<{ [P in O]: T[P] }>;

const a: OptionalKey<Entity, 'b'> = {
  a: 'a',
}

const ab: OptionalKey<Entity, 'b'> = {
  a: 'a',
  b: 'b'
}

const ac: OptionalKey<Entity, 'b'> = {
  a: 'a',
  c: 'c'
}
```

The idea is pick all the properties that want to make optional, then merge with the type than we want to make the property optional.

You can check this in [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20Entity%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20a%3A%20string%2C%0D%0A%20%20b%3A%20string%2C%0D%0A%20%20c%3F%3A%20string%2C%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20OptionalKey%3CT%2C%20O%20extends%20keyof%20T%3E%20%3D%20Pick%3CT%2C%20Exclude%3Ckeyof%20T%2C%20O%3E%3E%20%26%20Partial%3C%7B%20%5BP%20in%20O%5D%3A%20T%5BP%5D%20%7D%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20a%3A%20OptionalKey%3CEntity%2C%20'b'%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20a%3A%20'a'%2C%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20ab%3A%20OptionalKey%3CEntity%2C%20'b'%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20a%3A%20'a'%2C%0D%0A%20%20b%3A%20'b'%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20ac%3A%20OptionalKey%3CEntity%2C%20'b'%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20a%3A%20'a'%2C%0D%0A%20%20c%3A%20'c'%0D%0A%7D)

Answer (score 2):

Simple version of accepted answer (use [Intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of a [Partial](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype) and [Pick](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys)) without any intermediary types to confuse things:

```
type Entity = {
  a: number,
  b: number,
  c?: number,
}

type Ham = Partial<Entity> & Pick<Entity, Exclude<keyof Entity, 'b'>>;

const b: Ham[] = [{ a: 1 }, { a: 1, b: 1 }, { a: 1, c: 1 }, { a: 1, b: 1, c: 1 }]; // OK.
const c: Ham = {}; // Bad.
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogdsAlqKBeKBvAUFKBDALijgFcBbAIwgCcAaHKCo0ym+3AYwH5nyq6sAXyxZQkKAAk8ZNFAAKeakjwAbADzwkoAHxQAZPMQcA1hoTIQtWAA8OKkgBMIa4xBAB7AGaxzoKwHIKf21tAG4RDnc4AGdgfCJNC1kMeKgARismdKsOIjSoYUiYuKypMgBtAF1ZcpTCdIKrOrzMvMbMVIyoXIbBJs7W7O62wUrwgHpx7qjY4clpZMFQqEmoACE8BwA6IA)